# Need to make Wordpress popup responsive

Tags: css, responsive-design

I have a newsletter popup window for wordpress. It works perfect on browser and ipad, but the popup is not displaying properly in iphone.

Any thoughts how to make is responsive? it has a custom CSS option to be added.

Answer (score 0):

Set the width of the popup to `max-width:100%;`. It's a little hard to know exactly what you need as we don't know how its built and why its not responsive. Are you able to link to a demo of this popup?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can download Ninja popup.
2. Its easy to configure and responsive also.
3. More samples popup is there you can send mail function also.